# Quand peut-on mettre un adjectif avant ou après un nom ? — When do adjectives go before or after a noun?

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs, ordre-des-mots

Quelles sont les règles quant au placement des adjectifs avant ou après les noms ?

Exemples :

- *Un **bel** animal* (avec en prime le changement *beau* → *bel*… règle ?)
- *Une **belle** maison*
- *Une **verte** prairie* — *une prairie **verte*** (différence ?)
- *Une maison **bleue***
- *Ma **petite** sœur*
- *L'allée **principale***

---

What are the rules concerning the position of adjectives?

Comment: C'est souvent bonnet blanc et blanc bonnet... ;-)

Comment: Je crois me souvenir que c'est au cas-par-cas et qu'il existe une liste (pas si longue) d'adjectifs qui se placent avant le nom: beau, grand, petit... Quand aux autres (tels que "verte prairie") il s'agit d'un usage à titre "poétique" qui n'est pas standard...

Comment: Tiens, ici on dit plutôt "chou vert et vert chou" (D'ou l'album correspondant des Schtroumpfs, "Schtroumpf Vert et Vert Schtroumpf".) https://secure.wikimedia.org/wiktionary/fr/wiki/bonnet_blanc,_blanc_bonnet

Comment: Du point de vue de la linguistique moderne, et en particulier du [TAL](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/fr/wiki/Traitement_automatique_du_langage_naturel), personne n'a encore réussi a identifier de règles utilisables. D'autant plus si on prend en compte le problème du placement relatif des épithète entre eux (*un pauvre petit homme* vs **un petit pauvre homme*)

Comment: @Joubarc: Et les Verts Schtroumpfs ils ont des blancs bonnets ou des bonnets blancs ??

Comment: Il me semble qu'il y a un différence subtil entre *un âge certain* et *un certain âge*.

Comment: @Benjol correct, voir aussi [l'exemple de F'x](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/323): _un ancien moulin_ vs. _un moulin ancien_

Comment: Un minuscule commentaire pour rappeler que le choix de *avant* ou *après* dépend essentiellement de l' **idée** que l'éditeur veut **faire passer**... (Vous noterez la pirouette quand j'écris que:) En fait, ce n'est pas vraiment un commentaire minuscule.

Comment: @ℝaphink - Curieux, j'ai toujours dit l'inverse.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

La place de l'épithète par rapport au nom remplit plus d'une dizaine de pages du *Grevisse* (de §325 à §332 dans l'édition 2008). J'essaye donc ici de faire une synthèse des principes généraux :

- “La postposition est l'ordre le plus fréquent”
- “Les linguistes ont essayé de trouver [des] principes généraux”, mais l'auteur doute de leur caractère général en raison du nombre d'exceptions historiques et stylistiques. Parmi les règles avancées :

  - “L'épithète postposée apporte une information nouvelle ; antéposée, elle n'est qu'une qualification banale, attendue.”
  - “L'épithète est objective quand elle suit, subjective quand elle précède.”
  - “Les adjectifs antéposés ont un sens assez large, peu précis.”

Se placent *ordinairement* **avant le nom** :

- petit, vieux, bon, grand, joli, autre, mauvais, jeune, gros, beau, et leurs comparatifs (moindre, meilleur, pire) ;
- les ordinaux (premier, second, dernier, etc.)

Se placent *ordinairement* **après le nom** :

- les adjectifs de forme et de couleur
- ceux dérivés d'un nom propre (*cornélien*), ou désignant une catégorie (*juif*, *royal*, etc.)
- la plupart des participes (présents et passés)

Suit une grande liste d'exceptions, ainsi qu'une liste des adjectifs ayant un sens différent lorsqu'ils sont antéposés ou postposés. Exemple : *un ancien moulin* (un moulin qui n'est plus en activité) et *un moulin ancien* (un moulin dont la construction est ancienne).

---

The position of the attributive adjective in relation to the noun fills a dozen pages of the *Grevisse* (from §325 to §332 in the 2008 edition).  I will try to summarize the general principles:

- “Postposing is the most frequent order”
- “Linguists have tried to find general principles”, but the author is uncertain of their general attribute considering the number of historic and stylistic exceptions. Some of the advanced rules:

  - “The postposed attributive adjective provides new information; when it is preposed, it is only a mundane, expected description.”
  - “The attributive adjective is objective when it is after and subjective when it is before.”
  - “Preposed adjectives have a vaguer, less precise meaning.”

The following are *usually* placed **before the noun**:

- *petit, vieux, bon, grand, joli, autre, mauvais, jeune, gros, beau* and their comparatives (*moindre, meilleur, pire*);
- ordinal numbers (*premier, second, dernier*, etc.)

The following are *usually* placed **after the noun**:

- adjectives of colour and form
- adjectives derived from a proper noun (*cornélien*) or designating a category (*juif*, *royal*, etc.)
- most participles (present and past)

There is a then a long list of exceptions, as well as a list of adjectives with a different meaning if placed before or after the noun. Example: *un ancien moulin* (a mill no longer in use) and *un moulin ancien* (a mill built a long time ago).

Comment: Au moins je sais quel livre demander à Noël.

Answer (score 17):

Le truc que je donne à mes élèves en seconde langue est BANGS.  BANGS représente les adjectifs qui vont avant le nom.

B - Beauty (ex: beau, laid)
A - Age (ex: jeune, vieux)
N - Number (un, premier)
G - Greatness (bon, excellent)
S - Size (grand, gros, petit, minuscule)

Comment: Très intéressant! Cependant, instinctivement, je dirais que minuscule va habituellement après le nom, mais ça peut très bien être un cas de bonnet blanc, blanc bonnet.

Comment: @Kareen, mettre _minuscule_ après le nom qualifié me semble ajouter de l'emphase.

Answer (score 14):

L'adjectif se place après le nom, sauf dans les très nombreux cas, difficiles à cerner précisément, où il se place avant — voir 
[le résumé de F'x, ou Grevisse](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/319/quand-peut-on-mettre-un-adjectif-avant-ou-apres-un-nom/323#323). Pour traiter les exemples donnés dans la question :

- *Beau* (et *joli*) se placent en général avant le nom : « un bel animal », « une belle maison », « une belle femme », « un joli garçon », ... Par contre, d'autres adjectifs du même champ sémantique se placent après : « un animal mignon », « une maison laide », ... On peut des fois dire « un homme beau », « une femme belle » (mais c'est rare) ; il y a une nuance de sens que je ne parviens pas à expliquer.

  Au passage, la forme *bel* s'utilise uniquement lorsque le mot qui suit commence par une voyelle et appartient au même groupe. En gros, cela veut dire qu'on emploie *bel* lorsque l'adjectif est antéposé à un nom masculin qui commence par une voyelle : « un bel animal », « un bel homme », mais « un beau chat », « un beau houx », « un homme beau et grand ». Il y a quelques subtilités comme l'expression figée « bel et bien » (ainsi que « bel et bon »). L'adjectif *nouveau* a une forme *nouvel* qui suit la même règle (« un nouvel indice ») ; je crois que ce sont les deux seuls cas. Historiquement, beaucoup de mots en -au ou -eau sont le résultat d'une déformation de -al ou -el, et c'est justement ce qui s'est passé pour les formes *beau* et *nouveau* ; cela se retrouve par exemple dans les noms en -al dont le pluriel se forme en -aux.
- Les adjectifs de couleur se placent après le nom, il ne me vient pas d'exception à l'esprit. (Ce qui ne veut pas dire qu'il n'y en ait pas.) Quand j'entends « une verte prairie », je pense à de la poésie ; la poésie peut facilement changer l'ordre des mots. En prose, j'écrirais et je dirais « une prairie verte » (sauf effet de style délibéré).
- Les adjectifs de taille se placent en général avant le nom, mais il existe un certain nombre de locutions dans lesquels « grand + nom » ou « petit + nom » a un sens précis, et on place alors l'adjectif après le nom lorsqu'il a son sens littéral. Voici quelques exemples.

  - *Petite sœur*, *grand frère* désignent l'ordre dans une fratrie (*younger sister*, *older brother*).
  - Un *grand homme* est un homme dont on vante les qualités, souvent une personne célèbre et positive (*a great man*). Pour parler d'un homme de grande taille, on dit « un homme grand » (*a tall man*). On utilise rarement *grande femme*, même si la libération des femmes au vingtième siècle a commencé à faire rentrer le terme dans la langue (*grande dame* n'a pas tout à fait les mêmes connotations). L'adjectif *grand* antéposé peut avoir le même sens avec d'autres noms qui désignent des personnes (« un grand écrivain », « un grand orateur », ...).
  - Un *petit garçon* est un enfant mâle jeune ; si l'on veut spécifiquement insister sur la taille, on peut dire « un garçon petit ». C'est un peu plus naturel pour une fille ; une *petite fille* est jeune, une *fille petite* est de petite taille (et une *petite-fille* est une fille d'une fille, le féminin de *petit-fils* et dual de *grand-parent*).
- Les adjectifs qui classent un nom dans un ensemble de manière absolue se placent en général avant le nom : *le meilleur moyen*, *la pire chose*, *la première fois*, *le vingtième siècle*, *le dernier arrêt*. On peut aussi placer des superlatifs absolus avant le nom lorsqu'ils sont suffisamment courts : *la plus grande maison* ou *la maison la plus grande* (le sens est le même).

  Au contraire, les adjectifs qui classent de manière relative se placent en général après le nom. C'est le cas des comparatifs : *un monde meilleur* (sous-entendu, meilleur que le monde actuel), *une pire chose* (pire qu'une autre). C'est également souvent le cas des adjectifs qui ont une valeur intensive : *un élément essentiel*, *un ouvrage mineur*.

  Attention, il y a des exceptions. Par exemple, s'agissant d'intensifs, on peut dire *un richissime homme d'affaires* ou *un homme d'affaire richissime*. Les adjectifs *minimum* et *maximum* se placent toujours après le nom (en tout cas je ne vois pas d'exception), peut-être parce que ces mots ont longtemps été seulement des noms et que c'est le long usage en apposition qui les a transformés en adjectifs (*une valeur [qui est un] minimum*).

  Pour le mot *principal*, le placer avant ou après a donc une nuance de sens. *Une allée principale* est une des allées les plus longues ou les plus importantes, sachant qu'il peut y en avoir plusieurs qui ont une importance à peu près égale. Si l'on parle de *la principale allée*, c'est qu'il y en a une qui est plus importante que les autres. Quand à l'*allée principale*, qui est le cas le plus courant, c'est encore autre chose : l'adjectif a bien une valeur absolue (c'est l'allée la plus importante), mais on n'insiste pas sur ce fait : « la principale allée » insiste plus sur *principale* tandis que « l'allée principale » insiste plus sur *allée*.

Comment: Une femme belle, rare? Pas tant que ça :-)

Answer (score 3):

Pour les gens intéressés par cette question, je recommande la lecture de [Syntaxe du français parlé vs. écrit : le cas de la position de l’adjectif épithète par rapport au nom](http://tipa.revues.org/1066) (Thuilier 2013) qui donne une analyse multifactorielle de la position.

> au niveau lexical : les adjectifs courts, fréquents et simples ont tendance à être antéposés, tandis que les longs, rares et construits tendent à être postposés.

.../...

> au niveau syntaxique, nous observons que, de façon générale, la nature du déterminant influence la position : les déterminants démonstratifs, possessifs et les articles définis favorisent l’antéposition. La présence de propositions relatives, de syntagmes prépositionnels ou d’un autre adjectif après le nom favorise également l'antéposition.

.../...

> les syntagmes adjectivaux contenant des adjectifs coordonnés ou des modifieurs adverbiaux ont tendance à être postposés, ce qui va dans le sens de la tendance à placer les constituants plus complexes après le nom.

Comment: @Legomononc'bléd'Ingres Le problème des analyses multifactorielles est que dans un même temps elles montrent l'influence des différents facteurs sur le phénomène observé et elles étouffent l'explication dans un nuage de chiffres inextricables. Je recopie quelques éléments de la conclusion dans la réponse pour voir si ça répond à votre demande...

Answer (score 1):

Before or after depends essentially on what's more important (most important has to appear first).

So sometimes it may be useful to find other words to express a thought, if this helps to locate most important words at the beginning of a phrase.

While people who like to see project be born would say:

- Un projet certes onéreux

trying to place the “bad” word as late as possible (adding maybe some unnecessary words like `certes`, which would be an abbreviation of `certainly` but minimizing his effect).

People who find the project too expensive would say

- Un coûteux projet

Changing *coûteux* for *onéreux*, as in “un onéreux projet”, doesn't sound well.

Comment: C'est pas faux, mais ça n'aide pas à deviner quels sont les adjectifs qui vont devant et quels sont ceux qui vont derrière (ou les deux).

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Hé non, hélas. Je me rend bien compte que cela semble compliquer plus qu'autre chose, cependant si un anglophone cherche à comprendre pkoi tel auteur à dit ceci comme cela, tenir compte de ce type d'habitudes peut aider.

Answer (score -1):

Référence: Le Français déchiffré, clé des langues et du langage. Henri Adamcweski.
Place de l'adjectif dans le groupe nominal: bonnet blanc ou blanc bonnet?
Pages 214 à 216

Comment: Une citation ou un résumé manquent à cette réponse. Un lien serait aussi bienvenu.