# How do you tackle 'adjective overload' when translating to French?

Tags: traduction, adjectifs

In English, you can happily pile on adjectives before a noun (e.g. the big fat ugly green alien), in French, not so much. On top of that, in French some adjectives go before and others afterwards (I humbly admit to never having taken the time to work out why, mostly intuited).

This is something where literal translation just won't cut it, and periphrase work-arounds can just clutter up your text.

What rules of thumb do professional translators use in these cases? Just jettison some adjectives?

<sup>(ported from [EN-FR proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1979/english-french-translation/2097#2097))</sup>

Comment: Do you mean "paraphrase"? Although "periphrase" ties in nicely with your "work-arounds".

Comment: Je crois il a écrit périphrase qui manque une accente http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%A9riphrase

Comment: I'm confident you can pile quite a lot of adjectives too, but with certain typographic rules, such as the use of commas and _et_. _Une magnifique grande maison rouge, spacieuse et bien ensoleillée._ If you care to throw English examples at us, I'm sure we'll make a decent job of translating them to French no matter how long.

Comment: As for position of adjectives: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/319/quand-peut-on-mettre-un-adjectif-avant-ou-apres-un-nom

Comment: [circumlocution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumlocution), not periphrase, apparently.

Comment: @Stéphane: thanks, I thought there was one but couldn't find it... and, ermm, it's one I asked myself. (I was looking at the tags `adjectifs` instead of `adjectif`)

Comment: @Stéphane, I'm going to have to get into the habit of actually searching here for answers :)

Comment: @Joubarc: use `[tag:adjectifs]` for tags, looks like [tag:adjectifs] in comments, they are hyperlikinfied.

Comment: BTW, Usually, the order of the adjectives when there are several is reversed when compared to English. (Obviously complicated by the before/after choice).

Comment: @Stéphane thanks for the tip (took me a moment to understand that you were not telling me how to look for the question...)

Comment: @Benjol one more thing... in whatever order you put the adjectives, don't forget the noun.

Comment: @Stephane, having looked at the answers to that question, I'm thinking that intuition was easier and possibly more reliable :)

Comment: English has orders for adjectives too, but most people don't realize it. "The fast green car" is slightly different than "The green fast car".

Comment: @Benjol a comment regarding [the issue ofaccepting answers](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/q/161): I couldn't help but notice that you didn't accept answers for most of your questions. I wonder if you could do so, or indicate why you're not satisfied with the answers by editing the questions (and thus bumping them to the front page).

Comment: @Fx, several reasons. 1) I sometimes don't think to. 2) Often (so far) the pearls don't come first, so I wait. 3) I don't always feel qualified to judge, so I also tend to wait to see what the community thinks. 4) After all that, I tend to forget :) So thanks for the reminder...

Answer (score 13):

You can also pile adjectives in french, before and after the noun.

I don't think there's any formal rule. This is mostly a question of style and usage ([the section "Épithète liée" of this article](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntaxe_de_l%27adjectif_en_fran%C3%A7ais#.C3.89pith.C3.A8te_li.C3.A9e) explains this an interesting way). In certain specific cases, the position of the adjective changes the meaning (the article above includes a few words about that as well) but this is also a question of usage.

So we would say:

> Le gros alien vert
>
> Le gros alien vert et moche
>
> Le gros, grand et affreux alien vert et malpoli
>
> L'alien vert, grand, affreux, et malpoli

But we wouldn't say (but in poetry, maybe):

> Le gros, grand, affreux, malpoli et vert alien
>
> Le bleu alien moche

Even if all of the sentences above are actually not incorrect.

And, specific case:

> Un alien sale (*an alien that is dirty*)

doesn't mean:

> Un sale alien (*a bloody alien, not to use an f-word*)

Anyhow,

> Le gros vert Alien
> cloche
> courait dans la plaine
> moche.
> La lune était pleine,
> proche ;
> pour lui quelle aubaine :
> roches !
> (Mais il se cassa tout de même la figure).

Comment: Le poème mérite un +1 à lui tout seul.

Comment: See also: [How can adjective-noun order in French be explained by parameter theory?](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/1163/how-can-adjective-noun-order-in-french-be-explained-by-parameter-theory/2456#2456)

Answer (score 3):

I think a reasonable paraphrase would be "[noun] who/which was [adjective,adjective,...]"

For example:

> L'alien qui était grand, gros, moche, et vert...

Or even more compactly:

> Le grand alien gros moche vert...

Either way, I'd put all or all but one of the adjectives *after* the noun (maybe you want to put one adjective which is the primary one - here, "big" - before the noun, but you could put them all after it).

However, it looks like native French speakers are also fine with doing things in a more "English" way and putting most of the adjectives *before* the noun (although leaving one *after* the noun which you'd never do in English), eg.:

> Le grand, gros et moche extraterrestre vert...

Comment: _Le grand, gros et moche extraterrestre vert_ works for me.

Comment: J'avais _l'affreux, gros et gras extraterrestre vert_ (subtilement différent de _l'affreux, gros et gras, extraterrestre vert_).

Comment: @Joubarc But does it sound better than putting the adjectives after the noun?  Somehow putting the adjectives after seems like more natural French to me.

Comment: [It's complicated](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/323).