# Quand doit-on placer les adjectifs de taille devant des noms ?

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs, ordre-des-mots

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Quand peut-on mettre un adjectif avant ou après un nom?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/319/quand-peut-on-mettre-un-adjectif-avant-ou-apres-un-nom)

J'ai lu qu'on peut se reporter à l'acronyme « BAGS » lorsqu'on tente de placer un adjectif. Si l'adjectif est dans l'une des catégories de l'acronyme (*beauty*, *age*, *good/bad*, *size*), il se place normalement  devant de le nom.

Mais, voir cet exemple:

> a great man - un grand homme
>
> a tall man - un homme grand

Dans le sens litéral de taille, l'adjectif suit le nom ! Pourquoi ?

Comment: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/319/quand-peut-on-mettre-un-adjectif-avant-ou-apres-un-nom - une question similaire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pour des adjectifs aussi **courants** que *grand*, *petit*, ou *beau*, en plus de se placer devant le nom, le groupe que cela forme (*un petit homme*, *un grand monsieur*, *de beaux draps*…), employé très couramment au fil du temps, a pris certaines **connotations**.

Pour obtenir le sens littéral de ces adjectifs, on « casse » ce phénomène en plaçant l'adjectif après le nom, *et ça sonnera bizarre*, parce que le sens — connoté — le plus courant de l'adjectif est « évité ».

---

As **very common adjectives** such as *grand*, *petit*, or *beau* are **employed so frequently**, the groups they form with many common nouns somehow become expressions, with **a sense of their own**, not being the exact sum of the adjective and the noun.

If you want to express the adjective literally, you have to “break”  this association, and put the adjective after the noun (everyone will acknowledge it's a bizarre way, only you need it in that case, and it will be understood as such).