# Word order with “prochaine”: before or after noun rules?

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs, ordre-des-mots, indications-de-temps

Why is it that when I want to say “The next week”, it's:

> La semaine prochaine

But when I want to say “The next meeting”, it's:

> La prochaine réunion

Is there a specific set of rules for the word “prochaine” to determine whether it goes before or after the noun? Is the rule related to time (day, week, month, etc.)? Are there any other words that follow this same rule?

Comment: Question might be related to these ones : [*Quand peut-on mettre un adjectif avant ou après un nom?*](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/319/quand-peut-on-mettre-un-adjectif-avant-ou-apres-un-nom), [*“ma jolie femme” vs “ma femme jolie”*](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2134/ma-jolie-femme-vs-ma-femme-jolie), [*The difference between Un petit garçon vs Un garçon petit*](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2567/the-difference-between-un-petit-garcon-vs-un-garcon-petit)

Answer (score 16):

The difference in meaning induced by the position of *prochain* might be hard to grasp, but for sure the word order is related to the meaning. Here are two concrete cases where the word order is definitely important.

- *First example.* Context: a meeting takes place regularly on Mondays but only once every two weeks. If during one meeting (or even in private, outside the meeting) someone says:

  > Vous n'aurez pas la réponse avant le prochain lundi.

  then, without too much doubt, the speaker refers to the Monday where the next meeting will take place (in two weeks). Now, if he says:

  > Vous n'aurez pas la réponse avant lundi prochain.

  he definitely speaks about the next Monday like in next week's Monday.
- *Second example.* Context: Someone is speaking about a book series, three of those books are already out.

  > Attendez-vous à une parution prochaine !

  This means that a new book will appear very soon, so be prepared!

  > Attendez-vous à une prochaine parution !

  This means that there will be a next one! (Even though it might be unexpected).

**Towards an understanding**. The adjective *prochain* identifies the **next** occurrence (or one among next occurrences) in a sequence whose elements are most probably ordered according to the speaker's time referential. However, when it's placed after the noun this adjective has a slightly different purpose, it implies some kind of temporal proximity (not only next, but **soon**).

Two remarks:

- This “soon” meaning is only possible with events or actions (and it must obviously be related to time), it cannot be applied directly to objects. The following sentences are correct:

  > Préparez-vous à l'arrivée du prochain train. (*next*)
  >
  > Préparez-vous à l'arrivée prochaine du train. (*“soon*”)

  The following is not:

  > *Préparez-vous à l'arrivée du train prochain.
- If *prochain* comes together with an adverb, then its position becomes mostly irrelevant. There's hardly any difference between “*La très prochaine nomination*” and “*La nomination très prochaine*”. In both cases, the meaning is “which will happen very soon”.

Comment: Also interesting regarding the idea of "soon" is the extension ([vielli ou littéraire selon le TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/prochain)) of the proximity to the spacial and even figurative domains. What comes to mind is Valéry's *Le cimetière marin* : « Amour, peut-être, ou de moi-même haine? / Sa dent secrète est de moi si **prochaine** / Que tous les noms lui peuvent convenir! »

Answer (score 11):

The placing of an adjective can be a tricky question in French. Here are some examples I found, which make the most thorough set of rules I have seen so far.

When speaking about "the one who/which will replace the current one", it goes before:

> *OK:* Ma prochaine voiture, ma prochaine maison, ta prochaine télévision, etc.
>
> *NOT OK:* Ma voiture prochaine, etc.

When used in the meaning "the first to arrive, to show up", it is also placed before the noun:

> *OK:* Le prochain bus, le prochain avion, le prochain rendez-vous, le prochain repas, etc.
>
> *NOT OK:* Le bus prochain

With dates (days, weeks, months, etc.), it's usually placed after.

> *OK:* Lundi prochain, le mois prochain, le week-end prochain, etc.
>
> *NOT OK:* A prochain lundi !

Now you may ask "why can we say *la prochaine semaine, le prochain week-end* ?". In that case, I'd say you're talking specifically about "the first to arrive".

When talking about an event coming up soon, you may choose which one you want to use:

> Nous nous reverrons lors d'une prochaine occasion / Nous nous reverrons lors d'une occasion prochaine.
>
> A un jour prochain ! / A un prochain jour !

Comment: Did you find this somewhere or did you draw conclusions from your own observations?

Comment: I have never seen anything related to these adverbs called "controversial". Where did you get that? THe closest thing is the broader issue of defining which adverbs go before or after a noun (and for that there is no clear-cut rule).

Comment: I agree with Circeus, nothing contrevorsial in the use of *prochain*.

Comment: What I was saying is that even though the position of the adjective is usually set (prochain is an adjective, not an adverb), there is no strict rule regarding "prochain". I used here the examples of this thread (as I said in my answer), which are the bests I have found so far : http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=170145

Comment: Despite the controversy on controversial, this is an excellent answer ! Your last point deserves some nuance, since prochain can also mean "in near term": taking the example of another answer, " la prochaine fin du monde"  is not exactly the same as "la fin du monde prochaine": the latter refers to an event in a near term (= "proche"), whereas the former may refer to the near term or the next event of a serie.

Comment: Please, could you make more explicit in a comment what you mean by "probably the most founded answer I have seen so far"? Could  you mean by that "probably the most **well founded** answer I have seen so far"?

Comment: @LPH : I meant that this is the most complete / thorough set of rules I found. I guess this formulation is more appropriate, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 7):

#### When used with a plural noun:

*Prochain* is one of those adjectives (along with *autres*, *premiers*, *derniers*, *mêmes*, and probably more, I checked in [Grevisse](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Bon_Usage) and it indicates the list is not complete) that will be placed before the noun when associated with a number or quantifier (hence the plural).
“*Dans les deux prochains mois*” (“*dans les quelques prochains mois*”) and not “**dans les prochains deux mois*” (“**dans les prochains quelques mois*”).

When not used with a number “*dans les prochains jours*” is usual but “*dans les jours prochains*” is possible.

#### When used with a singular noun:

The meaning might change when placed before or after the noun (combined sometimes with the use of a definite or an indefinite article).

- “*La semaine prochaine*” means “next week”. We would not normally say (but artistic license may permit it otherwise and that would  not be incorrect) “*la prochaine semaine*”.
- “*Une semaine prochaine*” would mean the same as “*dans les prochaines semaines*” (not necessarily *next* but just *coming*). “*Une prochaine semaine*” is also possible.

Used with a noun not connected with a period of time (like *semaine*, *mois*, etc.) its meaning changes depending on whether it's placed before or after. With some nouns it can only be placed after or before.

- “*À la prochaine réunion*”: *prochain* here implies a sequence without giving a lapse of time, it means the meeting following the previous one,  the meeting could be in days, months, years… But “*la réunion prochaine*” implies that the meeting is close in time (it's a synonym of *proche*).
- “*La fin prochaine du monde*” means the world is close to its end. There's only one expected end, no possible arrangement in a sequence. “*La prochaine fin du monde*” would sound like a nonsense except in a sci-fi context where it would mean “the next end of the world” (implying there's already been at least one previous end of the world).

Comment: I have just heard "le mois dernier" and "cette dernière semaine" in an interview in France 24. Do the determiners "ce"/"cette" make any difference in the position of prochain/dernier ? If so, it'd be nice to add it to your answer.

Answer (score 6):

I would say that when referring to time, you would put *prochain(e)* after the noun, but always when using a singular form:

> La semaine prochaine, j'ai rendez-vous chez le dentiste.
>
> L'an prochain, tu seras majeur.
>
> Jeudi prochain, il sera en congés.

For any other case (i.e. referring to time but in plural, or anything different than time), I would use it the other way around:

> Dans les prochains jours, nous vous enverrons le rapport.
>
> Le prochain train partira dans 2 heures.
>
> La prochaine fois, tu feras plus attention.

Comment: Certaines expressions peuvent enfreindre ces principes : "Les jours prochains nous iront à Paris."

Answer (score 3):

I think *prochain* (and *dernier*, which seems to have the same, or a similar pattern) are placed after if the noun expresses a period of time of a day or longer (*jour, semaine, mois, année, saison*, names of days, months and seasons...) and is an adverbial phrase within the sentence (we say "la semaine prochaine", but "au cours des prochaines semaines").

Answer (score 2):

En tant qu'adjectif, le sens premier est synonyme de **proche**.
`très rapproché, le plus rapproché`.

*Dans l'espace*, synonyme de voisin (près de) :

- vieilli ou littéraire : 
  `"On porta le vieillard au prochain cimetière" (Victor Hugo).`
- dans un mouvement (qui vient juste après le lieu où l'on se trouve) :
  `le prochain arrêt, la prochaine station.`
- Elliptiquement :
  `Je descends à la prochaine!`
- Négation : se dit pour exprimer une distance assez grande :
  `Ce n'est pas à ces prochaines maisons`,

*Emploi courant* :
Qui est près de se produire (synonyme : **imminent**)

- `Un jour prochain`, que l'on peut remplacer, par bientôt.
- Pour ne pas prononcer le mot mort et signifier une mort imminente :
  `La fin prochaine` [d'un malade en phase terminale].

*Usages spéciaux* :
**qui suit chronologiquement** (une autre date) :

- `Lundi prochain, le 1er janvier prochain.`

*Antéposé* d'un événement, synonyme : **suivant** :

- `la prochaine rencontre, le prochain train` : la rencontre ou l'arrivée du train sont des événements qui vont se produire dans un futur que l'on peut prévoir.

*Dans une série* :
**Qui viendra immédiatement après** :

- `Ma prochaine voiture, le prochain candidat (le candidat suivant).`

*La première fois que la chose se reproduira* :
**La fois prochaine** ou **la prochaine fois** :

- `La prochaine fois que j'irai hors de [l'espace Schengen][1], je n'oublierai pas mon passeport` [sous-entendu, je viens de me faire refouler aujourd'hui].

*Familier* :

- `à la prochaine!` pour dire "au revoir" (et non "adieu", qui dénoterait un départ dans retour, sans *prochaine* rencontre possible).

*Les usages connotés* :

- Grammaire : 
  Le *futur prochain* est formé avec un auxiliaire :
  `je vais ouvrir.`
- Didactique :
  *Genre prochain* :
  `"le plus faible, en extension, de ceux qui comprennent une espèce donnée" (Lalande).`
- Philosophie :
  *Cause prochaine*, celle qui précède immédiatement l'effet, synonyme : **direct**, **immédiat** :
  `Il est très vraisemblable que, si César n'ordonna pas la mort de Pompée, il fut au moins la cause très prochaine de cette mort (Voltaire)`
  `L'éclair est la cause prochaine du tonnerre.`
  *Pouvoir prochain*
  `Ainsi, lui dis-je, avoir le pouvoir prochain de passer une rivière, c'est avoir un bateau, des bateliers, des rames et le reste, en sorte que rien ne manque. (Pascal)`

Exemples relevés dans Le petit Robert ou Le Littré.
[D'autres exemples (CNRTL)](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/prochain)

---

Comme la question porte *sur l'ordre de l'adjectif prochain et d'un nom*, il faut préciser que la francophonie n'adhère pas toujours rigoureusement aux règles académiques et les assoupli parfois ; il n'est pas certain qu'oralement ces exemples aient un sens si marqué :

Un voyageur demandant le "train prochain pour .. ?" sera dirigé vers le bon quai de départ ; dans ce contexte, avec l'expression visuelle ajoutée, l'inversion de la position des mots n'entraîne pas de changement de sens.

Imaginons un test au travers d'une porte ouverte, entendre "Candidat prochain" ferait se lever le candidat suivant, et non celui le plus près de l'entrée : le contexte psychologique pour un auditoire moyen (échantillon de personnes représentatif des publics les plus couramment rencontrés, échantillon de l'audimat par exemple) ferait entendre 'suivant' pour prochain, d'autant plus que la phrase normalement prononcée est "Personne suivante" (ce qui évite de plus tout problème d'identification de genre).
Sans compter que certains chercheraient un Monsieur ou une Dame *Prochain*.

En revanche sous la rubrique 'dans une série' si l'on inverse la position de l'adjectif, on retrouve officiellement la notion d'espace : la voiture voisine ou le candidat le plus proche, mais le sens est bouleversé, rendant l'intelligibilité de ces paroles très incertaine.

*Prochain* est aussi un nom, qui peut induire en erreur, ou amener des difficultés supplémentaires :

"Papa dans un futur prochain, M. Prochaine, prochain après le candidat prochain, samedi prochain épousera sa prochaine prochaine, à la prochaine mairie devant ses prochains et son maire prochain, mariage dont la cause prochaine fut son récent divorce. Bon, à la prochaine !"
adjectif, nom propre (imaginé pour l'exemple), adjectif, adjectif,
adjectif, adjectif, nom (pour [sa seconde ou énième femme, sinon celle-ci ne serait pas sa prochaine] femme), adjectif, nom (pour sa famille et ses proches), adjectif, adjectif, adjectif.

N.B. : 'Les usages connotés', renvoient à des exemples pratiquement inutilisables et/ou incompréhensibles hors de leur contexte.
La citation du *[genre prochain](http://books.google.fr/books?id=g0xEyrr0AJgC&pg=PA84&lpg=PA84&dq=genre%20prochain%20de%20l%27homme&source=bl&ots=ALpx6EeDaU&sig=_SRcDmXpCVfp-wcJTDcLFL42lag&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=pp_6T7HVK6PG0QWNsNiZBw&ved=0CD4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=genre%20prochain%20de%20l%27homme&f=false)* en est l'illustration idéale :
 
à la première lecture de cette phrase sortie de son contexte, un *homo sapiens* normal se demande qui de l'*homo faber* ou de l'*homo erectus* est son genre prochain? à moins que le singe y vienne jouer les chimpanzés.