# Difference in usage between “prochaine”, “suivant” and “et puis”

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, conjonctions

I know the literal meaning of these words—next, following and “and then (?)” respectively. But  today when I tried to say “next step” as “étape prochaine”, when I actually meant *next step*, I was corrected by a native French to “***étape suivante***”.

So now I doubt my initial understanding. Can you give some examples that clarify their sense?

Comment: This may help http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2817/word-order-with-prochaine-before-or-after-noun-rules

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a difference in meaning between "la prochaine étape" et "l'étape suivante".  The first will be used only for the nearest (in time or in space) of its kind to the speaker.  The second can be used in that situation but also for another implied or explicit reference point which is not the now nor the here of the speaker.

> Dans dix jours nous arrivons à Llassa.  L'étape suivante sera de trouver un interprète.  La prochaine étape est charger la voiture pour partir à l'aéroport.

We'll first load the car, then go to Llassa, then find a translator.

In

> Maintenant que les valises sont faites, la prochaine étape est de charger la voiture.

You could replace "la prochaine étape" by "l'étape suivante" although there is a slight difference of meaning and a native speaker will probably choose one or the other depending on the context, but I'd be hard pressed to explicit the nuance.

Comment: LThe first sentence is a bit ambiguous. The last part can be unserstood as a "third" step. I'm a native speaker and that's how i understood it after the first reading.

Answer (score 2):

Next step could be translated to "prochaine étape" or "étape suivante"

another example : "next stop" --> "prochain arrêt" or "arrêt suivant".

Next could be translated to "prochain(e)" as well as "suivant(e)".

[Here](http://lewebpedagogique.com/ressources-fle/files/2010/11/Place-de-ladjectif.pdf) is a document that explains where to put adjectives (.pdf in french)

Comment: Merci @M42: I see. Then how to order the adjective and the noun in general, since it seems my ordering was incorrect? It is confusing  since sometimes the adjective comes before and sometimes after.

Comment: @AbhimanyuArora: I'm afraid there aren't any strict rule ;-( . Usually the adjective is postposed but there are exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

**Suivant** (*next*) est utilisé dans une *suite* (ou *séquence*) pour préciser l'objet ou la personne qui arrive logiquement à la *suite* de celui que l'on vient d'évoquer.

Dans la [chanson de Jacques Brel](http://www.paroles2chansons.com/paroles-jacques-brel/paroles-au-suivant.html), il est le *suivant* de la personne qui le précède qui elle-même est la suivante de …

C'est le mot à employer dans une boucle programme pour traduire *next*

**Prochain** (*near*), dans le sens de *proche*, indique une proximité mais pas une contiguïté :

"La *prochaine* fois tu feras attention" (mais il peut y avoir d'autres 'fois' qui ne concerneront pas le cas précisément évoqué ici ou qui ne vont pas arriver dans l'instant qui suit).

Les idiomes concernant *prochain* ont été donnés dans les autres réponses.

**... et puis** indique qu'il n'y aura ni suivant ni prochain, que c'est le dernier de la liste qui va être traité.

> On entendit des coups de feux, et puis plus rien.

*Complément fournis par le petit Robert*

**Et puis** sert à introduire une nouvelle raison (cf. *D'ailleurs, en outre, du reste*)

> *Et puis* après tout, cela ne me regarde pas.

**Et puis ?** S'emploie pour demander : *quelle suite ?* quelle importance peut bien avoir la chose en question ? (cf. *Et alors ?*)

> *Et puis* quoi encore ? après une demande jugée déraisonnable,
>
> *Et puis* quoi? *Et puis* après ? Expression familière utilisée par celui ou celle qui est en attente d'explication. Souvent prononcé sur un ton insistant ou agressif.

Comment: J'ai plussoyé. En ce qui concerne **et puis**, pourriez-vous SVP éplucher comment est-ce qu'il "indique qu'il n'y aura ni suivant ni prochain" ? D'après http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1752042, **Et puis** est un synonyme de **et après** ? Je suis au courant qu'au surplus, **et puis** = de plus.

Comment: @LePressentiment ajouté la deuxième acception de ET PUIS. Pour '... et puis' : synonyme *et, plus*

Comment: Je vous suis reconnaissant.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer :

> L'étape suivante sera ...

"The **following** step will be ..."

While "prochaine" would be more easily translated into "next".

Answer (score -2):

**étape suivante**; les étapes sont au féminin.
C'est surtout utilisé pour les jeux vidéos, "the next level".
**exemple**:

> La prochaine étape sera à Saint-Germain, nous visiterons le Sacré
>   Cœur.

---

**étape prochaine**: "the soon step" , "the level after".

La prochaine station" ou bien "le prochain arrêt de car" se disent.

"le prochain arrêt de car" se prononce "le prochainarrêt de car" ce qui peut passer pour être "le prochaine arrêt de car".

**exemple**:

> je descend à la prochaine station, Joséphine m'y attend.