# Comment se rappeler des sens divers de certains adjectifs ?

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs, ordre-des-mots

D'après http://french.about.com/od/grammar/a/adjectives_fickle.htm,

> Generally speaking, when the adjective precedes the noun, it has a figurative or subjective meaning, whereas the adjective which follows the noun has a literal or objective meaning.

Plutôt que  mémoriser leurs maints sens dus à leurs placements, comment faire pour se les remémorer ?

Ceci est issu de la page 39 de *Schaum's Outline of French Grammar* de Mary Crocker:

[image]

Dans ces exemples, entre d'autres, comment est-ce qu'une acception est plus littérale ou figurée que l'autre ? Par exemple, dans un certain jour, je ne comprends pas comment certain "has a figurative meaning" ? Dans un risque certain, certain "has a literal meaning" ?

● D'ailleurs, en ce qui concerne **brave**, "a good fellow" <=> "a courageous man."

● Une robe neuve et une robe d'un style différent sont les deux "nouvelles."

Comment: Ce n'est que par leur place par rapport au nom que ces adjectifs prennent leur sens et la seule solution est de les mémoriser. La liste des adjectifs concernés est plus longue que ça. Le plus connu est certainement grand. Regarde aussi ces réponses : [1](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/2895/358) et [2](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/327/358). Les explications donnés sont bonnes, rien à ajouter. Tu trouveras d'autres exemples en cherchant les adjectifs concernés dans le [wiktionnaire](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionnaire:%C3%80_propos).

Answer (score 1):

> Une nouvelle robe :

C'est une robe de plus dans la garde-robe mais elle peut très bien avoir un style ancien ou même avoir été acheté d’occasion ou c'est la robe de ma grand-mère que je viens de récupérer.

> Une robe nouvelle :

Je parle du style de la robe, je ne sais pas si la dernière achetée, en tous les cas son style est nouveau, c'est un genre que je ne portais pas auparavant.

> Mon nouveau smartphone est vraiment nouveau :

Je veux dire que le smartphone que je viens d'acheter et qui s'ajoute à /remplace **un autre que j'avais déjà** (impliqué par le *nouveau* placé avant l'adjectif) est d'un style différent de ce qui se faisait jusqu'ici, a des fonctionnalités techniques mises au point récemment et que d'autres n'ont pas encore (impliqué par le *nouveau* placé après l'adjectif).