# Prochain vs. next (traduction français <-> anglais)

Tags: traduction, usage, faux-amis

*Prochain* peut être traduit en anglais par *next*, mais aussi par *this, upcoming*. Ainsi, par exemple, *le prochain bus* signifie *the next bus*, alors que *le weekend prochain* signifie *this/upcoming weekend* (plutôt que *next weekend* - *le weekend d'après*). J'ai vu cette dernière traduction produire pas mal de confusions dans des communications entre francophones et  non-francophones, qu'ils aient parlé anglais ou français.

En explication à cette question, ma déduction personnelle est que les mots *prochain* et *next* représentent des concepts différents :

- *prochain* signifie quelque chose de plus proche à ce moment-là, ce qui est vrai pour *le prochain bus* et *le weekend prochain* (*the next bus* and *the upcoming weekend*)
- *next* signifie le suivant dans la séquence: dans le cas du bus il s'agit du bus qui suit celui qui vient de partir, alors que dans le cas du weekend, il s'agit du weekend qui suit le weekend qui vient.

Néanmoins, en lisant [ce fil](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/2817/9870), je me suis rendu compte qu'il peut simplement s'agir de la position de *prochain* par rapport au nom qu'il qualifie (mais je ne pense pas qu'il contienne une réponse directe à ma question.) J'apprécierais donc une explication.

**Update**
Selon [*Modern French Grammar: A Practical Guide*](https://www.amazon.fr/Modern-French-Grammar-Practical-Guide-ebook/dp/B00IEC2CIY/ref=sr_1_1?keywords=9780415098519&linkCode=qs&qid=1662022882&s=books&sr=1-1), la position de *prochaine* depend du contexte:

> **10.2 Some adjectives are usually placed before the noun**
> [...]
> (b) some of these, in certain contexts, follow the noun:
> [...]
> and with days of the week, seasons, parts of the year:
> **l’été prochain**    next summer
> **la semaine dernière**  last week
> otherwise, they precede the noun:
> **le prochain arrêt**    the next stop
> **la première/dernière semaine des vacances**    the first/last week of the holidays
> **10.3 Some adjectives change their meaning according to their position**
> [...]

Neanmois, *prochaine* ne paraît pas parmis les adjectifs, qui changent leurs sens selon la position.

Je ne pense pas que ça donne une response complète sur la traduction/utilisation de *prochaine* et *next*. Il faut aussi mentionner les commentaires par @PeterShor et @jlliagre, que l'utilisation de *next* est aussi ambigue, vouyez les lines [ici](https://www.frenchtoday.com/blog/french-grammar/next-in-french/) et [ici](https://www.usingenglish.com/poll/717.html).

Comment: As far as I know *next* only differs from *prochain* when applied to certain time periods, like weekends, Junes, and Tuesdays. And not even all time periods; I believe that *l'an prochain* is always the same as *next year*.

Comment: Pour traduire *next* on a deux options : *prochain* et *suivant*,   parfois interchangeable mais pas toujours. Je peux dire « Zut, j'ai raté le bus, le suivant est dans 10 min ». [*Au suivant..*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XVWaGlpOPnY) ("Next one"). Je pense que ça peut réorienter ta réflexion.

Comment: « je viendrai le weekend prochain » i.e. le weekend qui suit le moment où je parle. « Je viendrai le weekend suivant/d'après » : je ne me place plus par rapport au moment où je parle mais par rapport à un moment implicite dans le contexte.

Comment: I read  "J'ai vu ce dernière traduction produire pas mal des confusions en communication entre des francophones and non-francophones, qu'ils parlaient anglais ou français."; what do you mean?

Comment: Actually, googling, it seems that what  *"next Tuesday"* means is just as confusing in French as in English. [See this webpage](https://www.frenchtoday.com/blog/french-grammar/next-in-french/).  So the big disagreement would be *le weekend prochain* and *next weekend*, which in English means *the weekend of next week,* just like *next Tuesday* means *the Tuesday of next week.*

Comment: @LPH I mean that I have seen people being confused about whether one talks about *this/upcoming weekend/Monday* or the one after it (the *next one*). And I have seen it happen both to French when speaking English and to non-French when speaking in French (I say *non-French* in reference to people who habitually speak English, but not necessarily native English speakers, including me.)

Comment: Then your sentence in French should be different.

Comment: @LPH Merci pour cette correction.

Comment: @PeterShor To me *le weekend prochain* is not ambiguous, it can only mean the upcoming one. If I meant the weekend of next week, I'd say *le weekend de la semaine prochaine* (it is not usual to  say *le weekend en huit* although it is quite understandable).

Comment: Je vais lire le "duplicate" - peut-être une des reponses repond à ma question... mais je ne pense pas qu'on peut vraiment parler de "duplicate" ici.

Comment: Oui, je ne pensais pas que mon vote allait entraîner une fermeture immédiate, je m'attendais plutôt au commentaire automatique "does this reply answer to your question" avec attente d'autre votes. La question est bien sûr différente mais des réponses à l'autre question montrent qu'il n'y a pas (non plus) consensus sur le sens de "prochain" et qu'il vaut mieux utiliser autre chose.

Comment: ***Next*** ne semble pas plus faire consensus que **prochain**, et probablement moins d'après [ce sondage.](https://www.usingenglish.com/poll/717.html)

Comment: This thread on EL [Which day does "next Tuesday" refer to?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/3841/12918). The most often has en entry in books on English usage.

Comment: Même entre français ce n'est pas clair. "On se voit lundi prochain ?" "Tu veux dire le lundi qui vient ?" "Non, le lundi suivant". Et les Parisiens diraient "On se voit lundi en 8" (pour "au moins 8 jours à partir de maintenant").

Comment: Dans certaine mesure, cette question est un *duplicate* de [la question d'EL&U](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3841/which-day-does-next-tuesday-refer-to) citée par None. Il n'y a pas de différence notable entre l'anglais et le français, le sens est *opinion based*.

Comment: @jlliagre je pense que la sommaire de la discussion ci-dessus pourrait servir comme une réponse. Simplement pour garder les raisons menant à ta conclusion pour les autres utilisateurs.

Answer (score 1):

Je pense que "prochain" jouit de plusieurs sens que "next", plus précis, ne concentre pas. Je dirais que le prochain est, selon le sens :

1. Ce dont on est proche ("mon prochain" est proche de moi devant Dieu par son égale et triste condition humaine, qui me renvoie la mienne).
2. Celui qui suit, s'il s'agit du prochain train. Avec, ce coup-ci, un sens assez bien retranscrit par "next".
3. Un chevauchement de ces deux idées, qui pourrait être vu comme la rencontre des deux premiers sens plutôt qu'un troisième, sans se réduire à aucun des deux : "Un jour prochain" n'est en effet ni "le jour suivant", ni nécessairement "un jour proche". Tout au plus peut-on dire (espérer) que c'est "un jour, à venir".