# Using more than one adjectives: “belle brosse à dents neuve”?

Tags: adjectifs, ordre-des-mots

In the following sentence

> J'ai une belle brosse de (not sure whether «pour» could be used here) dents neuve, mais je n'ai plus de dentrifice.

Is my ordering of adjectives okay? Could you refer a good link to learn these nuances of ordering adjectives in case noun complements are present?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> J'ai une belle brosse *à* dents neuve, mais je n'ai plus de dentifrice.

Ici on ne peut pas inverser les adjectifs : *beau, belle, bon, bonne* indique l'intérêt que l'objet a en lui-même, alors que *neuve* donne une qualité à l'objet dont on parle.

**EDIT** *après commentaire*

Les adjectifs qualifiant l'émotion que je ressens pour un objet se placent avant, alors que ceux qui définissent l'objet intrinsèquement s'y raccrochent après pour mieux le définir.

Comment: Donc, si l'intérêt que la brosse à dents a pour moi est qu'elle n'a jamais servi est que sa qualité intrinsèque est sa beauté, je devrais dire: _J'ai une neuve brosse à dents belle_ ?

Comment: @mouviciel Bonne lecture, texte amendé.

Answer (score 1):

Whether a nominal group contains a inseparable¹ complement introduced by a preposition doesn't change anything to the placement of adjectives. Some will go before the group, some will go after the group, as described here:

[Quand peut-on mettre un adjectif avant ou après un nom ? — When do adjectives go before or after a noun?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/319/quand-peut-on-mettre-un-adjectif-avant-ou-apres-un-nom-when-do-adjectives-go)

*Beau* always comes before the noun, and *neuve*, like most adjectives, goes afer.

—
<sup>1. Notice that *brosse à dents* is a single vocabulary unit, and thus quite different from *la robe de Marie* which one would qualify as “la belle robe neuve de Marie”.</sup>

Comment: "Beau" always comes before the noun  except when an enumeration of adjectives is used; there is then an other possibility, as this example shows: C'était un homme beau, jeune et actif. You still can write the following, as a rather equivalent way of expressing that: "C'était un bel homme, jeune et actif".