# Difference between beau and bel

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs

What is the grammatical difference between *beau* and *bel*? They are both the masculine singular form of the adjective *beau*, right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*"Beau"* and *"bel"* are both french adjectives of the some token. That is that *'beau'* becomes *'bel'* before a french singular masculine noun starting with a vowel or a mute 'h'. Hence, if we take the nouns *"Art"* and *"homme"*, the plural of beau stays unchanged while becoming plural: *"les 'beaux' arts"* or *"l'Ecole des 'Beaux' Arts de Paris"*.

So, *'beau'* keeps its form when qualifying a plural noun here, *'arts'*.

But if art was singular, it's 'bel' that would has been used.

Example: *"Quel 'bel' art !"* or *"Quel 'bel' homme !"* and *"Quels 'beaux' hommes !"* for the plural.

While using the same process we would have said: *"Quelle 'belle' femme !"* for the singular, and *"Quelles 'belles' femmes !"* for the plural.

We will here use the same process for:

> *"Quel 'vieil' homme !"* and *"Quels 'vieux' hommes!"*.

Where, 'H' is also mute.

Comment: _Beaux-arts_ prend le trait d'union et le sens de _beau_ y est peu usuel (l'idéal).

Comment: It also works for `nouveau` and `nouvel`

Comment: So it stays 'beau' if the word after is not the noun, even starting with a vowel? 'Un beau et puissant sentiment...' ?

Answer (score 11):

Actually, it is pretty simple. If there is a vowel after "beau", it becomes "bel":

> Il est bel et bien avocat.
>   Quel bel écureuil !
>   Quel beau cheval !

You can see more exemples and exercises [here](http://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-17423.php).

Answer (score 6):

"beau" is used by default.

The form "bel" is used when the next word starts with a vowel.

For example:

> - un *beau* **r**ocher
> - un *bel* **a**rbre
> - un *bel* **e**t grand édifice

Answer (score 3):

There are very few adjectives with 2 forms: short, before a noun begining with a vowel, and another often bigger, to put after the noun.

And it is for masculine, singular.

I see 4 cases (with help of M. Glisse):

- beau / bel
- vieux / vieil
- nouveau / nouvel
- fou / fol

Comment: fou / fol, etc.

Comment: There is also mou/mol.

Comment: mol ne s'emploie plus. voir quelques exemples (dernier en date 1911) https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mol

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are both the masculine form of *beau*, but *bel* is used when the noun after it starts with a vowel. For example,

> Un bel appartement

Note that *bel* is before the noun. Follow the rule called BANGS word. B stands for Beauty, A stands for age, N stands for new/old, G stands for good, and S stands for size. If any adjective falls in a category of BANGS, then it will go before the noun. Usually they go after the noun.

Comment: BANGS is more of a guideline than a rule; there are plenty of instances where adjectives fall in those categories but go after the noun anyway, see http://french.stackexchange.com/q/319/217.

Comment: It is incorrect. In fact, almost every adjectives can go before or after the noun. There are some exceptions: colors (but not always: "un noir dessein"). I dont see a lot.