# "une plus vieille femme" or "une femme plus vieille"

Tags: grammaire, ordre-des-mots, comparatifs

"She applied for the job, but they decided to hire an older woman with more experience."

> Elle a appliqué pour le poste, mais on a décidé d'embaucher une plus vieille femme avec plus d'expérience.

Normally *vieille* precedes the noun, but when it comes with the comparative *plus*, should it be placed after the noun instead?

> ... on a décidé d'embaucher une femme plus vieille ...

I tried to find a reference on this but failed. Maybe I didn't look for the right term.

Comment: related : [this question](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/319/7321)

Comment: We totally avoid using *vieux* / *vieille* when speaking about people, it is really rude in most cases. You should use *âgé* / *âgée*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, use "*plus âgé/âgée*", like Simon Déchamps said it's often rude to say "*vieux/vieille*".

Second, while "*plus vieille femme*" can be correct sometimes, here you would have had to go with "*une femme plus vieille*".

But there is no problem with "*âgé*" because you can't say "*plus âgée femme*". So you answer is :

> On a décidé d'embaucher une femme plus âgée avec plus d'expérience.