# Adjective before/after noun when preceded by quantifier

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs, comparatifs

As is well known, adjectives in French [sometimes go before a noun and sometimes after](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/319/quand-peut-on-mettre-un-adjectif-avant-ou-apr%C3%A8s-un-nom-when-do-adjectives-go). But what happens when an adjective is preceded by a quantifier like *plus*, *aussi*, or *moins*? Does it always go after the noun in this case?

"A study found that ... However, a more recent study found that ..."

> Une étude a trouvé que ... Cependant, **une plus récente étude** a trouvé que ...

or

> Une étude a trouvé que ... Cependant, **une étude plus récente** a trouvé que ...

"I hope I won't get such a bad professor again."

> J'espère que je n'aurai pas **un aussi mauvais professeur** de nouveau.

or

> J'espère que je n'aurai pas **un professeur aussi mauvais** de nouveau.

I asked [a question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/23421/une-plus-vieille-femme-or-une-femme-plus-vieille) with "une plus vieille femme"/"une femme plus vieille", but it's just one specific example. Is there a general rule and a reference on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In doubt, if you use a quantifier, always put the adjective after the noun :

> Une étude **plus récente**
>
> Un professeur **aussi mauvais**

Orally it's what sounds most natural, and will always be accepted. Sometimes you **can** put in in front of the noun **if you want**, but it sounds more formal.

So it's **always** correct after, and **sometimes** also correct before. I recommend you use it after unless you know exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks! Can you add something about when it is correct before?

Comment: Actually "*Un aussi mauvais professeur*" is correct, but sounds weird because it's rather formal and it's a sentence usually said by students, and they don't speak formal language. You could say "*Je n'avais jamais mangé un aussi bon gâteau !"*. (I know it's almost the same sentence !). I can also think of very literary phrasings, like "*On avait jamais vu un aussi bel ouvrage*". Like the others, you can say it before because you can say "*bel ouvrage*". If you say "*bien réalisé*" instead, you can't use it before the noun (with or without "*aussi*")

Comment: Thanks. Is it correct to say "Je n'avais jamais mangé un gâteau aussi bon !"?

Comment: Yes, absolutely ! Like I said, it's always correct to put it after the noun.