# Pourquoi les mots "une vieille lampe poussiéreuse" ne peuvent être placés dans un autre ordre?

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs, ordre-des-mots

Les mots "vieille" et "poussiéreuse" sont tous deux des adjectifs. Pourquoi ne peut-on dire alors "une poussiéreuse lampe vieille" par exemple ? Ou bien encore "une lampe vieille poussiéreuse" ?

Il est possible que ce soit techniquement autorisé, mais personne n'emploierait une telle formulation a priori.

Comment: Réponse très compliquée à mon avis, sans réelle règle mais plus une question d'usage. Voici un lien qui peut être intéressant (je l'ai survolé seulement) : http://monsu.desiderio.free.fr/atelier/adjordre.html

Comment: À moins que je me trompe, on peut dire "Une vieille, [et] poussiéreuse lampe" ou "Une poussiéreuse [et] vieille lampe". C'est surtout "vieille" dans ton exemple qui ne peut pas être placé après le mot (que je sache).

Comment: @TeleportingGoat "Une lampe vieille et poussiéreuse" ne me choque pas. Le "et" semble permettre plus de liberté.

Comment: @SimonDéchamps Je trouve aussi que "et" permet de faire à peu près ce qu'on veut. Après, je ne sais pas si la question porte sur uniquement les adjectifs qui se suivent ou si le "et" compte.

Comment: Probablement relié à ceci : https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/319/quand-peut-on-mettre-un-adjectif-avant-ou-apr%C3%A8s-un-nom-when-do-adjectives-go

Comment: @TeleportingGoat : "Une lampe vieille et poussiéreuse" est correct mais "Une vieille et poussiéreuse lampe" ne l'est pas. L'adjectif se met communément après le nom, surtout quand on les enchaine. Certains peuvent se mettre avant (comme "vieille", mais pas comme "poussiéreuse ") sans règle stricte sur lesquels sont valides

Comment: @AlexisLeGal Si il n'y a pas de règle stricte comment tu peux affirmer que c'est pas correct ? C'est courant dans la littérature de mettre des adjectifs avant le nom, je vois pas pourquoi "poussiéreuse" ne pourrait pas

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Dans les faits, il y a une règle, comme indiqué par le lien de Simon Déchamps, sauf qu'en pratique assez peu de gens les connaissant vraiment et déterminent l'endroit où placer l'adjectif par l'usage et l'habitude.