# La place des adjectifs qualificatifs

Tags: adjectifs, ordre-des-mots

Y a-t-il une difference entre  :

> 1. Un énorme scandale et un scandale énorme.
> 2. Une excellente université et une université excellente.
> 3. Un discours interminable et un interminable discours.
> 4. Une énergie extraordinaire et une extraordinaire énergie.

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non. Pas de différence dans les examples cités. *No difference in your examples.*

Mais il peut y avoir une différence dans certains cas: *But there can be a difference in some other cases:* Un grand homme (*a great man*) vs Un homme grand (*a tall man*)

Comment: Merci. Mais pourquoi dit-on une question difficile et la version difficile question n'est pas permissible ? S'agit-il des raisons stylistiques ?

Comment: L'adjectif après le nom est le cas le plus fréquent. C'est correct presque tout le temps. Pour plus de détails, voir cette question : https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/319/quand-peut-on-mettre-un-adjectif-avant-ou-apr%c3%a8s-un-nom-when-do-adjectives-go