# "Bonne nouvelle importante" ou "importante bonne nouvelle" ?

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs

Which sequence of adjective is correct?

- "bonne nouvelle importante"

or

- "importante bonne nouvelle" ?

Laquelle est la forme correcte ?

Comment: [Cette excellente réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/319/quand-peut-on-mettre-un-adjectif-avant-ou-apr%c3%a8s-un-nom-when-do-adjectives-go/323#323) sur la place des adjectifs épithètes contient les éléments pour répondre à ta question.

Answer (score 1):

Aucune des tournures suivantes n'est utilisée :

- une bonne importante nouvelle
- une importante bonne nouvelle

Ce sont des formules qui donnent une impression bizarre, une impression de caractérisations incompatibles, bien qu'il n'y ait aucune réalité dans cette idée.

Occasionnellement les tournures suivantes pourraient être utilisées ;
cela pourrait être le cas lorsque le locuteur veut distinguer une nouvelle particulière d'une masse de nouvelles qui sont simplement satisfaisantes.

- une bonne nouvelle importante
- une nouvelle bonne et importante
- une bonne et importante nouvelle

L'utilisation d'un seul des adjectif est une pratique standard mais la place de l'adjectif pose un problème de [contexte](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=une+bonne+nouvelle%2Cune+nouvelle+importante%2Cune+importante+nouvelle%2Cune+nouvelle+bonne&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cune%20bonne%20nouvelle%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cune%20nouvelle%20importante%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cune%20importante%20nouvelle%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cune%20nouvelle%20bonne%3B%2Cc0).

*courant* :             une bonne nouvelle
*peu courant* :      une nouvelle bonne
*courant* :             une nouvelle importante
*peu courant* :      une importante nouvelle

On pourrait aussi utiliser les formes suivantes;

- une bonne nouvelle qui est importante
- une bonne nouvelle qui est d'importance
- une bonne et importante nouvelle

Comment: Ça donne une « impression bizarre » tout simplement parce qu'il y a « une réalité » là-dessous : des usages que la majorité des gens respectent et donc on n'a pas l'habitude d'entendre certaines formes.

Comment: @Laure Je comprends bien cela : tout simplement, les gens ne le disent pas ; la question qui se pose c'est pourquoi  personne n'a l'idée d'utiliser ces formes, comme il est évident qu'il y a de bonnes nouvelles qui sont plus ou moins importantes; y a-t-il une logique contextuelle derrière cet interdit  ou bien une logique purement linguistique ou bien encore un phénomène psycholinguistique ? Je n'entrevois de réponse dans aucune de ces trois seules options.