# Position d'adjectif "excellent"

Tags: adjectifs, ordre-des-mots

Comme l'on lit dans cette **excellente réponse**
[Quand peut-on mettre un adjectif avant ou après un nom ? — When do adjectives go before or after a noun?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/319/quand-peut-on-mettre-un-adjectif-avant-ou-apr%c3%a8s-un-nom-when-do-adjectives-go/323#323)

> La place de l'épithète par rapport au nom remplit plus d'une dizaine
>   de pages du Grevisse (de §325 à §332 dans l'édition 2008).

Je me demande si des tournures comme **excellente réponse**, **excellente oeuvre** au lieu des plus traditionnelles **réponse excellente** et **oeuvre excellente** choqueraient les locuteurs natifs du français.

Par exemple

> Je vous félicite pour votre excellente oeuvre.

Ibid. pour l'adjectif **monumental**.

Par exemple.

> Le mécanicien et mathématicien Clifford Truesdell est l'auteur des monumentales oeuvres.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si on trouve ***excellent*** plutôt avant le nom ça tient au sens même de cet adjectif. L'adjectif exprimant un jugement, un réaction subjective, affective se place avant le nom. (Grevisse §398 10<sup>e</sup> édition, qui renvoie à l'article de Marouzeau « Encore la place de l'adjectif » dans  *Le Français Moderne*, oct. 1953, [p. 241-243](https://fr.calameo.com/read/0009039473e627990eacf?authid=FcLgsii5nHaQ)) :

> C'est une excellente initiative.

On peut bien sûr trouver *excellent* après le nom.

> La belle matière, la maturité du Chenin a bien été saisie dans ce vin excellent qui a su jouer le jeu de la fraîcheur avec cette finale sapide et minérale. ([In Vino veritas](http://www.in-vino-veritas.fr/les-appellations-meconnues/))

Selon l'analyse de Mazureau à laquelle renvoie Grevisse, ici *excellent* exprime une valeur discriminative qui classe le vin en question dans une catégorie (celle des vins excellents).

Comme le dit @petitrien ***monumental*** se place quasi exclusivement après le nom parce que, comme le dit Grevisse (§398 10<sup>e</sup> édition), les adjectifs exprimant une qualité physique se placent après le nom.

Cependant la même analyse faite ci-dessus pour « excellent » peut s'appliquer aussi pour « monumental ».

> Ce monumental ouvrage d’art offre un spectacle incomparable sur les montagnes environnantes. ([Site de l'Office de tourisme de Grenoble-Alpes](https://www.grenoble-tourisme.com/de/katalog/activite/les-forts-de-la-bastille-et-du-saint-eynard-293867/))

Dans cet exemple il me semble que l'adjective placé avant reflète l'affectivité du locuteur qui cherche de surcroît à attirer l'attention des touristes.

Autre cas similaire :

> Ce monumental échafaudage érigé il y a huit mois sera démonté à partir du lundi 15 avril.[(*La Provence*  11/04/2019](https://www.laprovence.com/article/edition-vaucluse/5452721/le-mur-a-livre-certains-secrets.html))

Answer (score 1):

*Excellent* est ambivalent, on le trouve avant ou après le nom.  Lorsqu'il est associé à un nom et que les deux constituent à eux seuls une phrase autonome, je l'emploierais plutôt avant le nom :

- Excellente initiative!
- Excellente question!
- Excellente idée!

*Monumental* par contre s'emploie le plus souvent voire exclusivement après le nom :

- une architecture monumentale
- une œuvre monumentale
- une erreur/bourde monumentale

Comment: Merci. Pourquoi cette différence entre excellent et monumental ? Quelle règle dicte leur position ?

Comment: @Dimitris      J'avoue que j'aurais du mal à énoncer une règle utile quant à la position de l'adjectif, c'est plus un sentiment que j'ai retranscrit.  Je suis sûr que  les grammairiens qu'il vous arrive de citer (Ferrar et Offord) ont réussi à systématiser ce problème sous forme de tendances fortes à défaut de règles infaillibles.