# drôle d'idée vs idée drôle

Tags: synonymes

I have read the following sentence in the book Le Petit Nicolas:

> Clotaire s'est levé et il a dit qu'il allait faire manger son livre d'arithmétique à Agnan, ce qui était vraiment une drôle d'idée.

Is there any difference in meaning or usage between "une drôle d'idée" and "une idée drôle" (= a funny idea)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Quand peut-on mettre un adjectif avant ou après un nom ? — When do adjectives go before or after a noun?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/319/quand-peut-on-mettre-un-adjectif-avant-ou-apr%c3%a8s-un-nom-when-do-adjectives-go)

Comment: @Toto no because the expression I'm asking about is "une drôle d'idée", not "une drôle idée". I think that "drôle" is a noun in the former, not an adjective?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista No, in *une drôle d'idée* "*drôle*" is an adjective, not a noun. *Une drôle idée* is impossible, the "de" is needed in front of the noun *idée*. *Une drôle d'idée* is just a set phrase. *Une idée drôle* is grammatically correct but  is never said. *Drôle* can be a noun - although not in your sentence - and is hardly ever used nowadays. It could be used -  might still be in some parts of France - to mean a kid.

Comment: @None Thanks for clarifying it. I have never seen an adjective used in such a way (after an article and before a preposition), only qualitatively (right before/after a noun) or as a predicative (e.g. cette idée est drôle). I guess that French grammar is different from the grammar of other Romance languages in this point.

Comment: @None : I think your comment should be an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Une drôle d'idée" is a strange, curious, or even crazy or absurd idea. It can be funny, or not.

Comment: AFAIK "drôle" can be funny or strange/odd, depending on context. I didn't know that it could mean only the latter in "drôle de". Thanks for making it clear.

Answer (score 0):

Complement: here is the history of this word as related in [La Grammaire Française](http://www.gabrielwyler.com/page028.htm), and an explanation of the construction with « de » that we find in this locution (from the same source).

> **I**   
>    Drôle
>    Historique
>    Drôle commençait sa carrière comme nom banal. Son féminin était « drôlesse ».
>    Dans un deuxième temps, « drôle » et « drôlesse » sont devenus des possessions prédicatives¹ : drôle de garçon, drôlesse de fille.  Ces formes sont analogues à « cette saleté de temps » et à « cette chienne de vie ».
>    Dans un troisième temps, « drôle de » est devenu un adjectif antéposé invariable en genre. Donc on ne dit plus « une drôlesse de femme », mais « une drôle de femme ».
>    Finalement la version postposée sans « de » s'est développée.
>    « Drôle de » (antéposé) est descriptif, « drôle » (postposé) est restrictif.
>    « Drôle de » admet le degré : les plus drôles de confusions.
>    « Drôle de admet » le pluriel : quelles drôles d'histoires.
>    On trouve l'adverbe « drôledement » dans la langue populaire de certaines régions.
>
> - ce drôle de bonhomme
> - cette drôle de bonne femme
> - ce drôle de Pierre
> - cette drôlesse de Marie
> - drôle d'histoire
> - histoire drôle

> **II**    L'introduction à la possession prédicative selon la même source ([ref.](http://www.gabrielwyler.com/accueil.htm)) ■
>    Définition et terminologie
>   Sur cette page, nous examinons un certain nombre de syntagmes du type
>   [nom-1 * de * nom-2]
>   qui ont pour particularité commune le fait que leur constituant de gauche (nom-1) est analogue à un prédicat et leur constituant de droite (nom-2) est analogue à un sujet. La source de l'expression « cet imbécile de grammairien » est « ce grammairien est un imbécile ». De même, la source de l'expression « l'île de Crète » est « Crète est une île ». « Grammairien » et « Crète » sont analogues à des sujets, « imbécile » et « île » sont analogues à des prédicats.
>   Pour plus de commodité, nous appelons le constituant de gauche la « possession » et le constituant de droite, le « possesseur », bien que les syntagmes que nous examinons sur cette page n'aient rien à voir avec la possession proprement dite. Quant au syntagme lui-même, nous le nommons la « possession prédicative ».

¹<sub>See "**II**"</sub>