# Where can I look up whether an adjective goes before or after a noun?

Tags: adjectifs, ordre-des-mots, ressources

The accepted [answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/319/quand-peut-on-mettre-un-adjectif-avant-ou-apr%C3%A8s-un-nom-when-do-adjectives-go) to "[When do adjectives go before or after a noun?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/319/quand-peut-on-mettre-un-adjectif-avant-ou-apr%C3%A8s-un-nom-when-do-adjectives-go)" highlights that it is somewhat arbitrary and hard to generalize.

For a given adjective, where can I look up whether it goes before or after the noun, or if the meaning would be different?

For example, I am hesitating about where to put the adjective "éventuel" when discussing a potential contract amendment. In [TLFi](http://stella.atilf.fr/Dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/advanced.exe?8;s=1821594285;), there are usages cited with both adjective-noun and noun-adjective orders, but it is not clear to me if the meaning is specific to a given order or if it's arbitrary.

> B. [En parlant d'un événement] Dont on ne peut savoir quand il se produira, ni même s'il se produira. Action, décision éventuelle; nomination, offre éventuelle; intervention éventuelle; utilisation éventuelle de qqc. Honoré avait réfléchi à tous les problèmes que posait la candidature éventuelle de Maloret (AYMÉ, Jument, 1933, p. 82) :
>
> > 3. les pastilles de menthe avaient disparu des pharmacies parce que beaucoup de gens en suçaient pour se prémunir contre une contagion éventuelle.
> >    CAMUS, Peste, 1947, p. 1310.
>
> ...
>
> C. [En parlant d'une pers.] Qui remplira une fonction donnée si certaines conditions se trouvent réalisées. Employeur, remplaçant, successeur éventuel; lecteur, utilisateur éventuel; ennemi éventuel.
>
> > Il avait calculé qu'il faudrait au moins une minute aux policiers ou aux agresseurs éventuels pour enfoncer la porte ainsi calée (ABELLIO, Pacifiques, 1946, p. 384) :

...

Comment: Even in the sentence by Camus, he could very well have written _contre une éventuelle contagion_, and it would have been the same.

Comment: There aren't any other fixed rules than those given in the answers you are pointing to. As already said *Grevisse* is probably the most comprehensive exposition. It will often be on a case by case basis.

Comment: Among all the example given in the [TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9ventuel) or [Robert](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/eventuel) I cannot find an example where changing the place would change the meaning. In some cases the choice may depend on sentence balance, so it's more about style than meaning.

Comment: @None, right, I get that it's case-by-case. But for a given case (i.e., a given adjective), is there a dictionary that specifies which placement(s) are acceptable? TLF does not.

Comment: If the place changes the meaning you will find the different meanings in a dictionary (although it may not be specified that the place matters), you can expect that if a particular adjective doesn't fall under the placement rules, both, before & after are acceptable.