# Is the phrase "mauvais ton" popular in today's French, and what's with the word order?

Tags: phrase

I'm told that the phrase "mauvais ton" should be translated into English as "in bad taste."

Is this true?

If so, is it popular in today's French?

Also: I know that in standard French, the adjective normally follows the noun it modifies, and not the other way around. So, why isn't it "ton mauvais" rather than "mauvais ton"?

Comment: Most of the time, French adjectives follow the noun, but there are some, like *bon* and *mauvais*, that almost always come before the noun.

Comment: See also https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/319/quand-peut-on-mettre-un-adjectif-avant-ou-apr%c3%a8s-un-nom-when-do-adjectives-go

Comment: "in bad taste" is "de mauvais goût". The other phrase, "de mauvais ton", is much rarer and has a more specific meaning, I would say, so I wouldn't translate it as "in bad taste".

Comment: @Stef: Okay, so: de mauvais goût applies to things characterized by such words as "tacky," "corny," "platitudinous," and so forth? Garish garments, jarring music, sugary snacks, atrocious architecture, and so forth?

Comment: @Ricky Yes, you got it.

Comment: I was so worried this was about the literal translation of "my bad" for how many kids I've had to tell that "mon mauvais" n'existe pas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this case, we would say ***[mauvais ton](https://www.expressio.fr/expressions/de-mauvais-ton)*** only, never *ton mauvais*, supposing that's the entirety of the phrase. I don't know that it's a "popular" sentence, but it's definitely in use, and it means something like "breaking the etiquette".

It's the opposite of the most common *[(**de**) **bon ton**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/de_bon_ton)*, that would even less support to be reversed (<s>de ton bon</s>).

[image]

For "in bad taste", we have "de mauvais goût", but of course there is some possible overlap between "mauvais ton" et "de mauvais goût", depending on the context.

See also: [When do adjectives go before or after a noun?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/319/quand-peut-on-mettre-un-adjectif-avant-ou-apr%C3%A8s-un-nom-when-do-adjectives-go)

Comment: and we even less say *de ton bon*! :-) By the way, *de mauvais ton* usually means 'breaking the etiquette' more than referring to the literal tone of a voice/text.